# Why does this SwiftUI code causing compiler to timeout

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

Does anyone have any idea why this code would cause my Xcode to go into meltdown. The CPU shoots up, the computer starts overheating, fans max out and I genuinely fear for my life. It ends up erroring out with: "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions":

```
struct MainView: View {
@State var index = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ZStack {
            if self.index == 0 {
                Color.red.edgesIgnoreSafeArea(.top)
            } else if self.index == 1 {
                Color.green.edgesIgnoreSafeArea(.top)
            } else if self.index = 2 {
                Color.blue.edgesIgnoreSafeArea(.top)
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions":
```

You've got the hint already. The compiler is basically having a hard time (I guess) to validate each and every expressions you have - I think this has to be improved by the Swift community.

Check again your code. You have multiple errors.

1. There's no such thing as `edgesIgnoreSafeArea`. Only `edgesIgnoringSafeArea`.
2. Check your last condition. You're using assignment operator `=`.
3. Your `ZStack` is kinda too complex. Make a method for that instead.

Applying these 3 things, you'll have something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var index = 0
    
    func getColorViewBasedOnIndex() -> some View {
        if self.index == 0 {
            return Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        } else if self.index == 1 {
            return Color.green.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        } else if self.index == 2 {
            return Color.blue.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        } else {
            return Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                self.getColorViewBasedOnIndex()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After eliminating things one by one, the culprit was point #2: Using the assignment operator in the condition check triggered some sort of recursive loop.

Answer (score 3):

It is some sort of compiler bug, but the trigger is a simple typo; You want `edgesIgnoringSafeArea`, not `edgesIgnoreSafeArea`.

You can simplify your code somewhat by using an array of `Color` -

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var index = 0
    
    private let colors = [Color.red,Color.green,Color.blue]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                self.colors[self.index].edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps even `private let colors: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue]`

Comment: I had that originally but I opted for type inference

Answer (score 0):

In my experience some kind of refactoring of inline child views into separate View structs or helper functions, as shown in the selected answer, is the way to fix this error.

So try this instead

```
struct ColorView: View {
    var index: Int
    
    init(index: Int) {
        self.index = index
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if self.index == 0 {
            return Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        } else if self.index == 1 {
            return Color.green.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        } else if self.index == 2 {
            return Color.blue.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        } else {
            return Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your main view file:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var index = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                ColorView(index: index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```